# getInpuBuffer in Android MediaCodec and MediaMuxer

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

Below is a fragment of Android MediaMuxer API sample code:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html

```
MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer("temp.mp4", OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
 // More often, the MediaFormat will be retrieved from MediaCodec.getOutputFormat()
 // or MediaExtractor.getTrackFormat().
 MediaFormat audioFormat = new MediaFormat(...);
 MediaFormat videoFormat = new MediaFormat(...);
 int audioTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);
 int videoTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);
 ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
 boolean finished = false;
 BufferInfo bufferInfo = new BufferInfo();

 muxer.start();
 while(!finished) {
   // getInputBuffer() will fill the inputBuffer with one frame of encoded
   // sample from either MediaCodec or MediaExtractor, set isAudioSample to
   // true when the sample is audio data, set up all the fields of bufferInfo,
   // and return true if there are no more samples.
   finished = getInputBuffer(inputBuffer, isAudioSample, bufferInfo);
   if (!finished) {
     int currentTrackIndex = isAudioSample ? audioTrackIndex : videoTrackIndex;
     muxer.writeSampleData(currentTrackIndex, inputBuffer, bufferInfo);
   }
 };
 muxer.stop();
 muxer.release();
```

For this line: `finished = getInputBuffer(inputBuffer, isAudioSample, bufferInfo);` I didn't find this function getInputBuffer in both MediaCodec.java and MediaMuxer.java, is that a user defined function or API function?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `getInputBuffer` is a hypothetical user defined function. It is not an API function. The comment above it explains what it is supposed to do. (Note how it wouldn't actually work in the way it is written, since the isAudioSample variable can't be updated by the function in the way it is exactly written either.)

Comment: Suppose I want to record video( encoding from surface ) and audio using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer API, shall I set timestamp for bufferInfo (both video and audio) explicitly or just use the default value?  Maybe some platform use different timestamps for surface and audio, such as boot time and monotonic time etc.

Comment: I would expect that the timestamps from mediacodec should work fine, assuming that you got proper input timestamps to the encoder.

Comment: @mewo1234 You should set the timestamp manually when using Surface input to a MediaCodec because you cannot associate a timestamp with a frame on MediaCodec input from a Surface. From my experience, failing to do so can lead to some skipped frames. This means you need to set the buffer info `presentationTimeUs` for output buffers from the encoder. You should not need to worry about timestamps for audio; the only thing MediaCodec cares about for input audio timestamps is that they are strictly increasing. MediaCodec should output the correct timestamps with its encoded audio samples.